# Syncing my Github repo to MS Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am new to VSTS and trying to sync my Github repos to the VSTS environment to completely integrate my working environment to it. I want to sync my Github repos to update whatever changes made on VSTS. This procedure is very confusing.

I followed this link: http://intranoggin.com/Blog/February-2017/Synchronizing-code-between-GitHub-and-VSTS.aspx

The new interface does not totally reflect the tutorial, but I was able to follow most parts. I did the followings:

[image]

I create a new definition of Builds

[image]

link it to my github repo

[image]

set access tokens

[image]

set task commands just as stated in the tutorial link above

[image]

save the definition and create a queue that runs the task

This worked well when I made changes a single branch in Github.

But what I am trying to do eventually is:

I want it to sync with the Repo itself including all Branches. So, if I create a new branch for Pull Request, I want it to get applied to VSTS automatically.

I really need help from someone who already has been using VSTS and knows how to make a complete Sync with Github repos and VSTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always make changes on VSTS git repo and need to sync github repo correspondingly, then you can **use one VSTS CI build definition** to achieve it.
Detail steps as below:

- Create a CI build with a PowerShell Task;
- Select the VSTS git repo in Get sources step;
- Enable continuous integration andspecify include all branches for Branch filters:

  [image]
- Add the powershell script for PowerShell task as below:

  ```
  git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  git remote add github https://username:password@github.com/username/reponame
  git push github $(Build.SourceBranchName)
  ```
- Make sure Fail on Standard Error option for PowerShell task is deselected:

  [image]

Now after any changes is made on the VSTS git repo, github repo will be updated automatically.

Comment: Great answer! Is there also a way to sync pull requests?

Comment: Yes, you can use VSTS web hook to tigger the pull request created event, and then create a pull reuest on github via github rest api (https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request).

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I would suggest to replace password with "PersonalAccessTokens", it is more secure.
This solution works for me, but even tough the GitHub repo is updated correctly, I get this error in the console which causes the build to fail:
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
##[error]Switched to a new branch 'master'
To https://github.com/me/myrepo.git
   2225935..fb28257  master -> master

What do you know what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build on every branch with VSTS, you need to edit the build definition and then set up an appropriate trigger. This way, builds will happen automatically instead of having to manually queue them.

[image: Build Definition Triggers]

The official [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts) on this is pretty good and goes into more detail.